# `RUID`, `EUID` and `setuid bit`

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to understand `RUID`, `EUID` and `setuid bit` stuff. Here are my questions in the topic:

1. In the [How to start (or find) a process with RUID different from EUID?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202322/how-to-start-or-find-a-process-with-ruid-different-from-euid) question the Gilles answer states:

   > It's only setuid executables that start with the effective UID set to
   >   the owner of the executable while the real UID remains the real UID of
   >   the invoking process

   What does it mean `the invoking process`? If I'm right that in the case of e.g. passwd command run by say Bill user with id = 1000 `the invoking process` mentioned above will be just the Bill user?
2. Am I right that when we take some action on a file inside an executable (e.g. write to that file) the system checks if it is allowed to do that by checking `EUID` of that executable with the file permissions?

   For e.g. we have executable `abc` (`setuid bit` not set) which writes some data to `1.txt` file with `-rw-r--r--` permissions. Bill user (UID=1000) runs `abc`. Now because `abc` EUID=1000 (no `setuid bit` set) and the `1.txt` permissions is `-rw-r--r--` the write operation is refused by the system because EUID=1000!=0?

Answer (score 0):

1) It says `the invoking process` because the passwd command in your example is launched by a shell (bash, csh, etc) or a program running with your ID.

2) Yes, you're right. Permissions arch checked against the process effective ID.